# How to set Box(contentAlignment=CenterVertically40%DownThePage)? Need advanced alignment option for Box

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose-layout

I'm building [this screeen](https://developer.android.com/static/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-compose-business-card/img/3e074bd51d2acbad_1920.png) from the Android Jetpack Compose lessons, and I want to somewhat-center-vertically the middle / 'Full Name' red box -- but I don't want it fully centered (i.e. 50% down the page), I want it 40% down the page, but the built-in 'contentAlignment' modifiers only cover 'Top', 'Center', and 'Bottom' -- I want something in between.

[image]

This is my current code, and it looks fine-ish, but I want to know how to manipulate the vertical alignment of the contents of the Box more fine-grained.

```html
@Composable
fun Profile(){
  Box(
    modifier = Modifier
      .padding(16.dp)
      .fillMaxSize(),
    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
  ,
  ) {
    Column() {
      // icon
      Text("aslkjdf",
        fontSize = 48.sp)
      // Full Name
      Text("aslkjdf",
        fontSize = 48.sp)
      // Title
      Text("aslkjdf",
        fontSize = 48.sp)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [**`BiasAlignment`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/BiasAlignment).
A bias of `-1` represents alignment to the start/top, a bias of `0` will represent centering, and a bias of `1` will represent end/bottom.

Just note that the `Alignment.Center` is defined as:

```
val Center: Alignment = BiasAlignment(0f, 0f)
```

You can use something like:

```
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .padding(16.dp)
        .fillMaxSize(),
    contentAlignment =  BiasAlignment(
        horizontalBias = 0f,
        verticalBias = -0.2f
    )
) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().border(1.dp,Red),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ){
        // icon
        Icon(Icons.Default.Email,"", modifier = Modifier.size(64.dp))
        // Full Name
        Text("FullName",
            fontSize = 36.sp)
        // Title
        Text("Title",
            fontSize = 24.sp)
    }
}
```

Inside the `-1, 1` range, the obtained alignment will position the aligned size fully inside the available space, using as center

```
val y = centerY * (1 + verticalBias)
```

[image]

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti what is `-0.2f` means in second argument of `BiasAlignment`

Comment: @vivekmodi it is the `verticalBias`. `0`  = vertical center, while `-1` is the top. Inside the `-1, 1` range, the obtained alignment will position the aligned size fully inside the available space, using as center `val y = centerY * (1 + verticalBias)`

Comment: Perfect thanks for great explaination